# webshot R-package capture unhide hidden div

Tags: r, r-package

I want to use webshot r-package to capture a web page but there is a small button which revel the hidden divs. How can I capture the page unhiding those divs.

Comment: Is the website running javascript? If yes, you'll have to first run the javascript and download the html. See https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scraping-javascript-generated-data-with-r

Comment: Yes, it is using javascript just to hide the answer section. But there is a button with which you can revel those hidden divs. The site is, http://arken.umb.no/~solvsa/STAT340/Exercise04.html

Comment: Anyway, I figured it out, I was trying to pass the jquery on eval parameter, but I needed to use casperjs. Thanks for you help!